# Passando model via parâmetro de forma dinâmica no .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Criei essa função para gerar um `handle` (ou `slug`, como preferir) para o model users, o problema é que eu gostaria de torna-na mais "modular", para que eu possa implementar facilmente em qualquer outro model que também seja necessário gerar um *handle*.

O model, que é uma *partial*.

```
public partial class users
{
    ...

    public void Handle()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

A função:

```
public void Handle()
{
    int length;
    string handle;
    List<int> list = new List<int>();

    handle = Slugify.Make(this.first_name + " " + this.last_name);
    length = (handle + "-").Length;

    this.handle = handle;

    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        List<string> handles = db.users.Where(p => p.handle.Contains(handle) || p.handle.StartsWith(handle + "-"))
            .Select(p => p.handle)
            .ToList();

        if (handles.Count == 0 || handles.Contains(handle) == false)
        {
            this.handle = handle;
            return;
        }

        if (handles.Contains(handle) && handles.Count == 1)
        {
            this.handle = handle + "-" + 1;
            return;
        }

        foreach (string index in handles)
        {
            if ((index + "-").Length > length)
                list.Add(int.Parse(index.Remove(0, length)));
        }

        list.Sort();

        int suffix = list.Last();
        this.handle = handle + "-" + (suffix + 1);
    }
}
```

Então criei uma classe separada que a princípio iria receber como parâmetro o *model* e então faria basicamente o que a função `Handle()` faz, mas de forma "modular", por exemplo:

Passando como parâmetro:

```
users user = new users
{
    first_name = first_name,
    last_name = last_name,
    email = email,
    password = BCryptHelper.HashPassword(password, BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt(6))
    handle = Handle.Make(db.users, first_name + " " + last_name)
};
```

A função:

```
public class Handle
{
    public string Make(Type model, string handle)
    {
        db.Set<model>.Where(...) ...

        return handle;
    }
}
```

Mas eu não consigo de forma alguma passar como parâmetro o model `db.users` sem determinar especificamente que o tipo deste `model` é `users`.

Já tentei `public string Make(DbSet<dynamic> model...` mas também não deu...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegue sim. Use genéricos:

```
public class Handle
{
    public string Make<T>(T model, string handle)
        where T: class
    {
        db.Set<T>.Where(...) ...

        return handle;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Para parametrizar o `Where`, conforme seus comentários, precisa definir uma interface para `T`:

```
public interface IHandle
{
    public string handle { get; set; }
}
```

Assim você pode usar o `Where`:

```
public class Handle
{
    public string Make<T>(T model, string handle)
        where T: class, IHandle
    {
        db.Set<T>().Where(p => p.handle.Contains(handle) || p.handle.StartsWith(handle + "-"))

        return handle;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

O modo de chamar o método é assim:

```
Handle.Make(user, "Rafael Alexandre");
```

Acredito eu que `db` esteja acessível dentro do método. Se não estiver, terá que ser assim:

```
    public string Make<T>(DbContext db, T model, string handle)
        where T: class, IHandle
    {
        db.Set<T>().Where(p => p.handle.Contains(handle) || p.handle.StartsWith(handle + "-"))

        return handle;
    }
```

Aí chama assim:

```
Handle.Make(db, user, "Rafael Alexandre");
```

Comment: Funcionou parcialmente, o problema é que o parâmetro handle não é reconhecido neste `Where`: `db.Set<T>().Where(p => p.handle.Contains(handle) || p.handle.StartsWith(handle + "-"))`.

Comment: `'T' does not contain a definition for handle`

Comment: Ah, bom. Significa que falta definir uma interface para funcionar. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Ainda não deu certo. Quando tento passar como parâmetro o `Handle.Make(db.users, "Rafael Alexandre")` o retorno é `The type System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.users> cannot by as type parameter 'T' in generic type or method 'Handle.Make<T>(T, string)`.

Comment: Não, jovem. Você não passa o contexto inteiro. Passa assim: `Handle.Make(user, "Rafael Alexandre")`, onde `user` seria o usuário. Eu vou editar a resposta mais uma vez porque acho que não ficou claro ainda.

Comment: E caso eu queira acessar assim (http://i.imgur.com/oP26o50.jpg) de alguma forma que funcione, é possível?

Aí chama assim:

`users user = new users { handle = first_name + " " + last_name }`

Comment: É possível assim. Experimente implementar. Caso dê algum problema, faça mais uma pergunta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41638/discussion-between-rafael-alexandre-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).